# How to close window programmatically after calling window.showdialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5, prism-4

I am creating a test method in which I am opening a window using `window.showdialog` method but until I click on the close button the execution of further code is not starts.

Here is my test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestProductView()
{
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

    ProductTreeDragDropViewModel viewmodel = new ProductTreeDragDropViewModel();
    System.Windows.Window window = new System.Windows.Window();

    ProductTreeDragDrop screen = new ProductTreeDragDrop();

    screen.ViewModel = viewmodel;
    window.Content = screen;

    window.ShowDialog();
    DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(9000);

 }

public  void DoEvents()
{
   DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
   Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new   DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}
```

**Note:** If I use window.show method then data are not being returned in the viewmodels's datasource.

Now, how to close the window programmatically after execution of `window.showdialog` method ??

Comment: The main problem is that code after "window.showdialog" is not executing... till I do not press colse button.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the dialog using ShowDialog, the control goes to the newly opened dialog. So you need to do the close operation in the launched dialog.

Alternatively, you can try

```
window.Show();
Thread.Sleep(10000);
window.Close();
DoEvents();
```

Comment: You are right krishna but I dont know how to handle newly opened dialog ?? can you help me for same ??

Comment: I am not sure what you are performing in the newly opened dialog. Please post the code from the screen you mentioned too. That may help.

Comment: I am creating test method therefore we can not change into code which is written in the actual window..

Comment: Just thinking aloud. In such case, you need to live with window.Show. You should launch the window, sleep thread for some time, close the window and doevents. The problem without sleep might be that after initiating the window to open, the system continues to DoEvents, but by then the actions that need to be performed in the window are not complete.

Comment: Updated the answer with the option. If this works, please vote and/or mark as answer.

Comment: No it will not work. I think u didn't get my question I must use window.ShowDialog method.